# In Model-View-Controller, is it ever okay for the view to depend on the model?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, application-design

The literature on Model-View-Controller (MVC) generally states that the model and the view are mutually independent entities, whereas the controller mediates their interaction and thus strongly depends on both.

At a theoretical level, the last statement seems like a sound approach by which to enforce modularity.

But suppose you've written an application that allows users to create, edit, and save documents. More sophisticated than simple textual documents, these documents consist of multiple fields, not all of the same type. It then occurs to you that, in order to polymorphically support multiple visual representations of the same document, you could define a DocumentView interface, which any concrete view subclass could adopt to indicate that it's able to display a document.

Now, suppose you've written the SomeDocumentView class, which adopts the DocumentView interface. To create the document view, your application code would have a line similar to the one below:

```
DocumentView documentView = SomeDocumentView(document)
```

Now suppose in the future, you've written the UpdatedDocumentView class, which also adopts the DocumentView interface. To make that change, you'd just need to replace the line above with:

```
DocumentView documentView = UpdatedDocumentView(document)
```

Voila! Your application code automatically supports your UpdatedDocumentView through the DocumentView interface.

But doesn't such a design violate MVC, because the view's implementation now explicitly depends on the model? Why's that necessarily a bad thing? If your model changes in the future, you'll have to change code regardless of your approach.

Answer (score 1):

"Model View Controller" has meant different things at different times. In the original MVC, in Smalltalk, the controller represented user input, and yes, views took model objects and represented them directly.

[Apple's MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) is more of an alias for [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) where, as you say, the presenter/controller acts as the middleman between the model and the view.

This pattern allows views to be developed independently. Likely in the case of your `DocuentView` it will actually be a composite and controller of several other views, thus blurring the distinction between view and controller.

One of the reasons UIViewController is called such is because it handles many of a views responsibilities, namely user input gestures. Using these features in modern code is generally frowned upon though. Apple provides more discrete mechanisms now.

Comment: You're exactly correct when you say that the view "will actually be a composite and controller of several other views, thus blurring the distinction between view and controller." That's been the primary motivation for me to decouple its functionality into two classes: a simple controller responsible for logic/manipulation of the model and a view that encapsulates an entire view hierarchy and handles gestures beneath one clean interface, so that its semantics resemble those of a single view. That architecture feels much cleaner, and adheres better to the SRP.  Is that an acceptable approach?

Comment: Your idea has the same motivation as MVVM, but your responsibilities are reversed from it. In MVVM, the ViewController encapsulates he view hierarchy while the ModelView is responsible for the logic/manipulation of the model objects. Each ViewController contains one ViewModel and no other model objects, the ViewModel contains all the model objects. So yes, I think your idea is sound, but the separation is a little cleaner with MVVM than your approach because the ViewController has some View like behaviors.

Comment: A link that might help: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/264081/usage-of-mvvm-in-ios

Comment: It's getting late in my part of the world. I'll post tomorrow to let you know if MVVM solves the problem. Thanks for the discussion so far.